# rsyslog only making log files in /var/logs

Tags: linux, centos, logs, rsyslog, logger

Running centos 7, my rsyslog.conf looks like this:

```
 59 # Log all the mail messages in one place.
 60 mail.* /var/log/maillog
 61 mail.* /var/log/logtest1
 62 mail.* /root/logtest
```

Then I use the logger command like so:

```
logger -p mail.err "this is one logsdsdfgsdfgdfsg"
```

Now this is written in the `/var/log/maillog` and `/var/log/logtest1`, but it's not written in `/root/logtest`.

I also ran `systemctl restart rsyslog` and also rebooted my system several times.

Is this intentional, or is it a bug? Either way, how would I force it to write my logs wherever I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have SELinux enabled ? if yes, then writing it into /root is bad idea. You need to label your /root/logtest directory as `chcon -t var_log_t /root/logtest` and probably `chcon -t var_t /root`